# Why determinant is defined in different way,when we have already simple definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am reading the topic determinant from the book hoffman & kunze.they have defined determinant as follows:

Let 
$K$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $n$ be a, positive integer.Suppose $D$ is a function from $n \times n$ matrices over $K$ into $K$. We say that $D$ is a determinant function if $D$ is $n$-linear, alternating, and $D(I)=1$.

We have already simple definition of it,which I have studied in high school.By simple definition we can compute determinant of $n \times n$ matrix by breaking up in to smaller $n-1 \times n-1$ matrices.and we know the computation of $2 \times 2$ matrix.Thus,determinant is already defined by induction in simpler way. We can also deduce all the properties of determinant by this simple definition.Then why should we define it in more complicated way when we have already one definition? Why do they introduce tougher definition?

Thank you

Comment: Because this definition allows you to prove if a function follows certain rules, that map is unique. And that's what we call the determinant map: $A\mapsto |A|$.

Comment: Welcome to the world of algebra.  Often, the more useful definition is not the explicit formula (i.e. the "high school definition") but the more concise and abstract definition.  For example, it is much easier to prove that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ using the "tougher" definition.

Comment: In particular, we can prove properties like this without ever having to explicitly compute a sum or product.

Comment: You have $D$ which is a function of the columns $D(c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n)$, and $D$ is linear in each column when you keep the other columns fixed.  Then you only need two properties to get determinant: 1. If you swap two adjacent columns, you negate the value of $D$ and 2. If the columns are the standard basis elements you get $1$ for the value. Don't you think that it's interesting and easier to understand than a permutation and/or cofactor definition? Also, did you ever try to show that the cofactor definition does not depend on how you carry it out? Lots of ways to do that expansion.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you mean,we define term in maths,by which we can prove some results in easier way?

Comment: @ramanujan To show that $\det\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\ 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 &25}=0$, would you rather break this into five $4\times 4$ determinants, and then break **each one of those** into four $3\times 3$ determinants, and $\dots$ **or** take one line to show that these rows are linearly dependent and then one more to conclude that the determinant must then be zero due to the fact that the determinant is an alternating, multilinear function of the rows?  The second way sounds much easier to me. 

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom and @Byeworld  And we can make theorems using simple definition (regarding properties of determinant) and then using that theorems we can prove such results(like $det (AB)=det(A)det(B)$ and problem byeworld posted).

Comment: Exactly.  Sometimes we like having several definitions for something (see the umpteen different definitions of the exponential function) because each one is better at proving some things than others.  As long as we can then prove that all of the definitions are equivalent, there are no problems in using whichever we think will make a given problem the easiest.

Comment: oh I got it!Like we have many equivalent definition of closed set,open set,compact set etc. in metric space.those all are equivalent,but we use that definition to solve the problem which make it easy.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a result which said that the vectorial space of $k$-linear alternated functions on a $n$ dimensional vectorial space is of dimension $\binom{n}{k}$. As your usual determinant on space of matrices $n\times n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ can be seen as a $n-$linear alternated function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (vectors point of view), it is a one-dimensional space and your definition just says that you take the "canonical" one.